# What's the difference between demixing temperature and cloud point?

Tags: polymers

I am learning something about polymer solution which has LCST phenomenon. But I met researchers used demixing temperature and cloud point to describe the transformation of this kind of solution from solutable into insolutable state. But for me, they seem the same. So I ask it here to learn what is the difference between these two concepts?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud point typically refers to the LCST (or UCST) in solution. Demixing temperature usually refers to the LCST (or UCST) of a polymer mixture or copolymer in bulk.